# How many ways are there to choose 8 coins from 100 identical pennies and 100 identical nickels?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is $9$ ways. There are $i$ pennies and $8-i$ nickels. $i$ can be $0,1,...,8$.

Why is the answer not ${8 \choose 0}+{8 \choose 1}+{8 \choose 2}+{8 \choose 3}+{8 \choose 4}+{8 \choose 5}+{8 \choose 6}+{8 \choose 7}+{8 \choose 8}$?

Comment: The given answer is counting sets.  Your answer is counting finite sequences.

Comment: Even if you imagined that each coin was unique, there would then be $\binom {100}8$ ways to do it, but it seems clear that we are to assume that all coins of the same denomination are indistinguishable.

Comment: @lulu It seems OP is assuming the positions of the coins matter. In that case, $8 \choose i$ would make sense.

Comment: @Haris  Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The pennies are identical. So are nickels. That means it doesn't matter which pennies or nickels are chosen. All that matters is how many of each are chosen. We can focus on the number or pennies (or nickels), the number of the other type will be automatically determined. Of the $8$ coins, $0$, $1$, $2$, ..., or $8$ can be pennies. So $9$ ways.

You are treating the situation as if the coins are arranged in sequence and it matters what positions are occupied by each kind of coin (which is clearly not what is asked). Meaning, if there are $i$ pennies, they can be occupy any of the $i$ positions, so $8 \choose i$ ways. Again, this is wrong and will result in a way bigger number that the correct answer.